# Visual code and NodeJs, inference of not installed packages namespaces

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, package

I am having an annoying issue. If

- 1. I start a blank Node project
- 2. no modules installed in it
- 3. I do a `import ''`, and, in between the brackets, I press `ctrl+space`, I get inferred some namespaces which should not actually be there.

I admit I probably did some wrong manipulation when learning how to code, but I tried to solve many of those things:

- I deleted the unnecessary globally installed packages
- I removed node_modules folders that I accidentally installed in my `/Users` folder.
  But I still get some of them referenced by VC inference:

[image: as you can see in this picture]

As you can see in the image I get some random inferred namespace. When trying to reach the originating folder by pressing `cmd` on Mac, VC doesn't highlight and create the usual hyperlink (when the package is actually there, VC creates a link to navigate to the references file).

How can I get rid of those fake namespaces?? hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Ok this one was super quick and simple, in fact in my `/Users` folder I forgot to delete a `package.json` file which was telling VC thats something was installed ....

> so, by my understanding, if a parent folder contains a `package.json` file it basically propagates down to the children folders...

Interesting to know!